Does all the adjacent vertices being on the same side of a hyperplane H containing the vertex imply H is a supporting hyperplane of the polytope?
I'm an undergraduate CS student and we're required to take a Linear Algebra course and I am  following the book by Lay, Lay and McDonald. Although we aren't required to learn about the geometry of vector spaces and linear optimizations, I actually liked to learn more about linear algebra. But I am having some problem to gain some intuitive, with some rigor maybe, sense of some results about convex sets and hyperplanes.
Consider the polytope $P = \text{conv} \{ \mathbf{v_i} \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid i \in I \}$ and the hyperplane $H=\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{x} = d \} $ such that $H$ contains a vertex $v_0 \in P$. Now, if the adjacent vertices of $v_0$ is in  $H^+$, the "nonnegative" side of the hyperplane, then is every vertex required to be in $H^+$ i.e. is $H$ a supporting hyperplane?
It can be very easily seen that in $\mathbb{R}^2$, H is indeed a supporting hyperplane using the fact that the angles at the vertices are always less than $180^\circ$ for a convex polygon. But generalizing it in even $\mathbb{R}^3$ seems hard let alone in higher dimensions.
And I understand that by the optimality test used in the simplex method for the associated linear programming problem, the value of $v_0$, according to the objective function $f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{x}$, is optimal and so $H$ is a supporting hyperplane of $P$. And in fact that's where I formulated the problem in the hope that it would be fairly easy to prove and would help me understand the theory of and give me some intuitive clarity of the simplex method. The book doesn't really have any rigorous theoretical foundation of linear programming and I tried searching online and through some books to understand the mechanics of the simplex method but they were fairly complex which would maybe need weeks of background reading. So, my best bet is the initial problem I posed to gain some understanding of the simplex method and so I can't use results from LP to prove the result.
So, I will appreciate it a lot if you can give some intuitive argument with some rigor if it's not too complex. And as an aside, I would also like to know which is the foundation of what? I mean does the theory of convex sets(and topology?) come first or the theory of linear programming?

Both $H^+$ and $H^-$ (which I will treat as being closed, so their intersection is $H$) are convex sets, and the intersection of convex sets is either convex or empty.
So $P \cap H^-$ is also a convex set, and since $v_0$ is a vertex of $P$ which is in $P \cap H^-$, it must be a vertex of that convex set as well.
Since $P$ is a polytope, it is bounded, and if $P$ contains any point not in $H^+$, then the ray from $v_0$ through that point must eventually exit $P$ through some face. If every vertex of $P \cap H^-$ forming that face lay in $H^+$, the entire face would, including the exit point for the ray. Which means the entire ray would lie in $H^+$. But the original point is not in $H^+$, so this cannot be. Thus if such a point exists, there is at least one vertex of $P \cap H^-$ not in $H$.
Which means $v_0$ has adjacent vertices of $P \cap H^-$ not on $H$. But such vertices of $P \cap H^-$ must also be vertices of $P$, as being a vertex is a "local" property: you can identify a point of a polytope is a vertex just by looking at the intersection of any convex neighborhood of the point with the polytope. The various sub-faces forming the boundary near the vertex are still boundaries of the intersection with the neighborhood, and are still convex subsets of the appropriate affine subspaces.
And these vertices must still be adjacent with $v_0$ in $P$, as the only new vertices created by the intersection with $H^-$ are on $H$. But all vertices of $P$ adjacent to $v_0$ lie in $H^+$ by hypothesis. So this contradicts the assumption that some point of $P$ does not lie in $H^+$.

Thanks. Your argument makes intuitive sense. I do have two questions though for further clarification/rigor:

Why do every vertex of any PROPER face(Q∩H) of a polytope(Q=P∩H- here) must have some adjacent vertices not in the face(and thus the supporting hyperplane)?
Carrying over from 1, why must any adjacent vertex of v0 not in the face of Q still be adjacent in P?
I am defining v1 and v2 to be adjacent iff there is a face containing only conv{v1,v2}. I'm not entirely sure if it's correct though. Also any direction about where I can learn the nitty gritty of these will be wonderful.


I was working from the assumption that $Q$ contains at least one point not in $H$. Thus as described in the post, there must be vertices of $Q$ not in $H$. The edges (dim-1 faces) of a polytope form a connected graph. If all the adjacent vertices of $Q$ to $v_0$ were within $H$, then every face with $v_0$ on its boundary would lie in $H$. But then the segments connecting $v_0$ to points of $Q$ outside $H$ would lie outside of all the faces, a contradiction. (2) the only faces of $Q$ not cut from faces in $P$ are in $H$. If $\overline{v_0v_1}$ is a face of $Q$ not in $H$, it is a face of $P$.
